# Read An Object In C# Which Is Created By Object.defineProperty In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, object, dynamic, defineproperty

in my JavaScript code section, an object is created with `DefineProperty` like this :

```
$("td", tr).each(function (index, td) {

            var field = $(td).attr("data-field");

            var value = $(td).attr("data-value");

            if (field != undefined && value != undefined)
                Object.defineProperty(DataToSend, field, { value: value });

        });
```

and then `DataToSend` is sent to a Url using post method and then the sent variable will be got in C# with a code like this

```
public ActionResult Edit(dynamic DataToSend) {}
```

how I can read the received `DataToSend` in csharp ?, I used gettype() and getproperties() from reflection, but those just give me a list with no member.

Comment: Why would you want to use a `dynamic` on your action? - Besides that: where is your `post` code? Do you use a form? or ajax?

Comment: What does the json from the browser end up looking like?